# Managing offline learning video courses

Tags: windows, video, collection-manager

I am looking for Calibre-like software to manage off-line learning video (such as from `coursera`, `Lynda` or from no-name author) courses saved on local disc.

All courses can be tagged and filtered by fields: Author, Language,  Publisher etc.

Each course can be divided into chapters (= directory on `fs`) an themes (= file). This structure can be borrowed from `fs`.

Learning progress (which chapter I have seen/time/last position saved) should be also tracked.

Video can be shown in embedded player `VLC` or other open source player with `SRT` support.

Comment: Any specific operating system, or should it be cross-platform like Calibre?

Comment: I am using Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to find a collection manager tailored specifically for offline training courses, however one of these two collection managers may fit your needs:

- [GCStar](http://www.gcstar.org/index.en.php) - has video play capabilities
- [Datacrow](http://www.datacrow.net/)

Comment: I will try to use `Datacrow`

Comment: It looks like VLC itself has your own collection manager