# Organise videos

Tags: windows, video, collection-manager

I have a huge video collection of TV shows and movies and they are stored on a hard drive shared over Samba and viewed using Kodi on my HTPC.

Is there a program on Windows (preferably free) that I can use to organise them?

- Organise into season, episode number.
- Log Changes (when I load new videos and new season to see my progress), new episodes rename etc.

Comment: There probably is. Question remains what features you want: what are must-haves, what are nice-to-haves, what no-gos? Must in plug in with Kodi – and if so, what information should be shared?

Comment: Very similar: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20522/managing-offline-learning-video-courses. You should really [search the site first](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+manage+videos) before asking. Similar links are also shown *automatically*  when you are typing your question.